# scater: SingleCellExperiment, Error in seq_len(ncol(assay))

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am trying to go through the following [scRNA-seq tutorial](https://f1000research.com/articles/5-2122/v2).

But the line `sce <- newSCESet(countData=all.counts)` is not working anymore with the most up-to-date version of `scater`. Now we should use `SingleCellExperiment` function instead, so when trying to do the following:

```
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(assays = list(counts = all.counts))
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in seq_len(ncol(assay)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(ncol(assay)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can better ask questions about bioconductor packages on [https://support.bioconductor.org/](https://support.bioconductor.org/), you'll probably get an answer from Aaron Lun himself within a day.

Comment: Which version of R and of the packages are you using? That workflow is for version 3.4 of Bioconductor, and the current  version is 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to use [the most recent workflow](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/simpleSingleCell/), which should be for the latest version on Bioconductor.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to transform your data.frame into a matrix. Just use these  two lines:

```
library(SingleCellExperiment)
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(assays = list(counts = as.matrix(all.counts)))
```